# update to Xcode 9 with errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

I recently updated to Xcode 9 and when I build my app I get a Apple Mach-0 Linker (iD) error. Before updating the project worked just fine. The error looks like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"__T0So22AVCapturePhotoSettingsC12AVFoundation01_abC16SwiftNativeTypesACWP", referenced from:
 __T09Lifelapse20CameraViewControllerC14capturePictureyyF in CameraViewController.o
"__T012AVFoundation39_AVCapturePhotoSettingsSwiftNativeTypesPAAE016availablePreviewc11PixelFormatG0SaySo8NSNumberCGfg", referenced from:
 __T09Lifelapse20CameraViewControllerC14capturePictureyyF in CameraViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not sure on how to fix this error, thank you.

Comment: did you Clear the XCode caches or clear particular project **DerivedData** . for example  `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. just deleted the derived data from that project and the 3 errors still show.

Comment: Also, if using a 3rd party library, it's possible that it's not built with the correct arm options.

Comment: @AndrewHarris Clear the CocoaPods caches and reinstall the dependencies CocoaPods library.

Comment: ok. I will try this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your error indicates that you're using a library named Lifelapse that itself is using AVFoundation. Please check your target settings and ensure you're linking to AVFoundation.

Answer (score 0):

There's an Xcode 9 bug apple made by mistake.They made some extensions were made private. You have to put `__` on those method calls.

**Example:**

Try changing  `let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!`

to

`let previewPixelType = settings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!`

***Apple accidentally made some AVFoundation API external protocols private hence the 2 undescores _ before the methods to access them.

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86810#259270

Comment: It happened to me too. You can mark my answer as the correct answer, if it worked for you.